# How can I run Golden tests in the Flutter Web integration test environment

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test, golden-test

I'm trying to run Golden test in the Flutter Web integration test environment.

But using flutter drive directly returns true without doing anything.

```
$ flutter drive   --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart   --target=integration_test/app_test.dart  -d chrome
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Running "flutter pub get" in golden_test1...                       387ms
Launching integration_test/app_test.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             14.0s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:58333/KzGPRO5qcEc=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58333/KzGPRO5qcEc=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic
00:00 +0: end-to-end test Golden test
Golden comparison requested for "main.png"; skipping...
00:00 +1: (tearDownAll)
00:00 +2: All tests passed!
All tests passed.
Application finished.
```

But if I use `flutter test integration_test --update-goldens` to test on desktop, it can support!

Unfortunately, `flutter test integration_test` can't run on Web.

```
$ flutter test integration_test
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Multiple devices found:
Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22000.978]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 106.0.5249.61
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 105.0.1343.53
[1]: Windows (windows)
[2]: Chrome (chrome)
[3]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"): 2
Web devices are not supported for integration tests yet.
```

So is there any way to run Golden test in web integration test environment?

Comment: I've faced same issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To get started testing in a web browser, [Download ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Next, create a new directory named `test_driver` containing a new file named `integration_test.dart`:

```
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart';

Future<void> main() => integrationDriver();
```

Launch chromedriver as follows:

```
chromedriver --port=4444
```

From the root of the project, run the following command:

```
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/app_test.dart \
  -d chrome
```

For a headless testing experience, you can also run flutter drive with web-server as the target device identifier as follows:

```
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/app_test.dart \
  -d web-server
```

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#5b-web

Comment: In the web environment, the flutter driver can be used for integration testing. Look here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction. So how to perform golden test under flutter driver?

Comment: @Riccardo, did you download ChromeDriver?

Comment: It says: To get started testing in a web browser, Download ChromeDriver.

Comment: I did. And It can be successful without the golden test.

Comment: I know all this. But I want to know how to run Golden test in flutter web integration test environment. You may try it

Comment: Try running `flutter test integration_test --update-goldens`. Does Terminal let you choose which device to run on?

Comment: Yes. It shows 'Web devices are not supported for integration tests yet.'

Comment: Did you launch chromedriver?

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Comment: @Riccardo sorry I don't think I can help you